# Ethereum address(generated) and ecrecover computed address is not matching

Tags: addresses, java

I created the Ethereum address by following the below steps .

```
         1. Generated a public key(ECDSAsecp256k1) from HSM. 
         2. Generated a Keeccak256 hash of Q point of ECPublicKeyParameters . 
            (Public key type : 
            org.bouncycastle.crypto.params.ECPublicKeyParameters)
         3. Took last 40 characters as Ethereum address
```

**Generated address** : 0x1e4d916EF29C292aC1c773e6e9C5e31879A65B59

By using the generated Ethereum address a transaction has been created and then signed(**SHA256withECDSA**) the message by private key(ECDSAsecp256k1) in HSM.i had r,s value as output of sigining.

Then with that r,s and v(27,28) value ,I tried a generate back ethereum address using the ecrecover method and it gave a different address.

**ecrecover output address** : 0x26EeeeCc7Dc04A302083522949E5e86B98c340e2

If i try with v value as (0,1) , getting the following address from ecrecover

**ecrecover output address** : 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000(v as 0,1)

Is there anything wrong in address generation or signing?

Comment: Have you tried with v(0,1)?

Comment: I tried with V as 0,1 also and getting same issue

Comment: What type of public key did you use? For ethereum addresses you have to concatenate both x and y. What hash function did you use to sign the message?

Comment: I am using the Public Key type  org.bouncycastle.crypto.params.ECPublicKeyParameters and "SHA256withECDSA" signing algorithm for message signing